# No known class method for selector 'labelColor' - react-native-image-crop-picker - for react-native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using react-native-image-crop-picker library within react-native application
Version details

```
react-native version: 59.10
 react-native-image-crop-picker: 0.25.3
 xcode: 10.1
```

While execution of code I am getting the error QBImagePicker/QBAssetsViewController.m:198:31: No known class method for selector 'labelColor'

```
195    // Info label
196    UIColor *labelColor = [UIColor blackColor];
197    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
198        labelColor = [UIColor labelColor];
199    }
```

I have tried to upgrade library version but issue is still there. can anyone please help

Thank you in advance

Comment: Xcode 11.3.1, react-native-image-crop-picker: 0.28.0, "react-native": "0.61.5", with no issues so far, perhaps you need to update.

Comment: Same Problem, did you find a solution Anu?

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (class, nonatomic, readonly) UIColor *labelColor  
        API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0), tvos(13.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(watchos);
```

I'm using XCode, and tripped over this. Note from the `UIInterface.h` definition (above) that it is unavailable for watchOS. If your code is like mine, and being used by WatchOS, then you will encounter the above issue.